# How to implement a DSL to dynamically create new methods via method chains?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I have a class and an instance of that class:

```
class Thing
   def initialize
      @name = name
   end
end

a = Thing.new("a")
```

I want to dynamically create methods and set their return values by calling a DSL like this:

If I write `a.is_a.person`:

- a `person?` method should be created for `a`
- `a.person?` should return `true`

If I write `a.is_not_a.man`

- a `man?` method should be created for `a`
- `a.man?` should return `false`

If I write `a.is_the.parent_of.joe`

- a `parent_of` method should be created for `a`
- `a.parent_of` should return `joe`

I tried doing this

```
class Thing
  attr_reader :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def is_a
    Class.new do
      def initialize base
        @base = base
      end
      
      def method_missing name
        @base.define_singleton_method "#{name}?" do
            true
        end
      end
    end.new self
  end

  def is_not_a
    Class.new do
      def initialize base
        @base = base
      end
      
      def method_missing name
        @base.define_singleton_method "#{name}?" do
          false
        end
      end
    end.new self
  end
end
```

And it works for `is_a` and `is_not_a` as defined above:

```
jane = Thing.new('Jane')

jane.is_a.person
jane.person? #=> true

jane.is_a.woman
jane.woman? #=> true

jane.is_not_a.man
jane.man? #=> false
```

But for the `jane.is_the.parent_of.joe`, like more deep chaining ones, I'm not able to figure out how I can implement it.

How do I approach this?

Comment: @user229044 when I write a.is_not_a.man it should able to create method man? in class Thing. So need to create methods dynamically. How Can i do this is my question.

Comment: Use `define_method`: https://apidock.com/ruby/Module/define_method

Comment: @KiranKumawat next time, please include your code right from the beginning to avoid having your question closed. Your post's [original version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/72620549/1) looked like you didn't have any code yet and expected us to write it for you. Now with your implementation it's quite clear what you are trying to do. (and quite interesting actually)

Answer (score 1):

With `Class.new` you create a new anonymous class each time `is_a` or `is_not_a` is called. Although this works, there's a
much more lightweight approach. You can create a helper that will invoke a given block each time it receives a message:

```
class MethodCallback
  def initialize(&block)
    @block = block
  end

  def method_missing(name, *args)
    @block.call(name, *args)
  end
end
```

Example usage:

```
m = MethodCallback.new { |name| puts "#{name} was called"}

m.foo
# foo was called

m.bar
# bar was called
```

With this helper, your class can be simplified like this:

```
class Thing
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def is_a
    MethodCallback.new do |name|
      define_singleton_method(:"#{name}?") { true }
    end
  end

  def is_not_a
    MethodCallback.new do |name|
      define_singleton_method(:"#{name}?") { false }
    end
  end
end
```

```
jane = Thing.new('Jane')

jane.is_a.person
jane.person? #=> true

jane.is_a.woman
jane.woman? #=> true

jane.is_not_a.man
jane.man? #=> false
```

Now, for the chaining one `jane.is_the.parent_of.joe`, instead of defining a new method right-away, we have to
invoke / return another `MethodCallback` instance in order to get an extra level of method chaining:

```
class Thing
  # ...
  
  def is_the
    MethodCallback.new do |name|
      MethodCallback.new do |value|
        define_singleton_method(name) { value.to_s }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In the above code, the first method name after `is_the` will be assigned to `name` and the second will be assigned to `value`.
The method we create will be called just like `name` and it will return `value`:

```
jane.is_the.parent_of.joe
#           ^^^^^^^^^ ^^^
#           name      value
jane.parent_of #=> 'joe'
```

Another one:

```
jane.is_the.major_of.london
jane.major_of #=> 'london'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not stuck on using method chaining to define your object, there are lots of alternatives.  Here is one that uses a "builder" approach.

```rb
class Thing

   attr_reader :name
   def self.define(name, &block)
      thing = Thing.new(name)
      thing.instance_eval(&block)
      thing
   end

   def initialize(name)
      @name = name
   end

   def is(str)

      case str
      when /^\s*a\s+(\w+)\s*$/
         define_a($1)
      when /^\s*not\s+a\s+(\w+)\s*$/
         define_not_a($1)
      when /^\s*the\s*(\w+)\s+of\s+(\w+)\s*$/
         define_relationship($1, $2)
      end

   end

   def define_a(str)
      define_singleton_method("#{str}?".to_sym) {true} 
   end

   def define_not_a(str)
      define_singleton_method("#{str}?".to_sym) {false} 
   end

   def define_relationship(relation, to)
      define_singleton_method("#{relation}_of".to_sym) {to} 
   end
end

a = Thing.define("a") do 
   is "a person"
   is "not a man"
   is "the parent of joe"
end

puts a.name       # => a
puts a.person?    # => true
puts a.man?       # => false
puts a.parent_of  # => joe
```